# Why is each security update file size so large?

Tags: updates, security, update-manager

The 'Software Updater' just asked me to download a security update which has a filesize of 62MB. And these updates are quite frequent. My questions are:

1. Why are they this big, if, by the frequency of these updates, I assume they fix only a few bugs each time?
2. Does it really eat up 62MB of my hard disk space, or are some previous files overridden by the new files? Or does the new files get deleted after it has 'done its thing'?

Answer (score 0):

As you are talking about recent security updates, Ubuntu have released more number of Security updates this time depending on all arch of systems.

If you want to see them please click here : http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/